# Django failing to route url (simple question)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm doing something stupid, and I'm not sure what it is.  I have a the following urls.py in the root of my django project:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', include('preview_signup.urls')),
)
```

In my preview_signup module (django app) I have the following urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^thanks/$', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'thankyou.html'})
)
```

The urls.py above doesn't work when I go to http://localhost:8000/thanks/.  But if it's changed to this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^$', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'thankyou.html'})
)
```

And I go to http://localhost:8000/ it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include('preview_signup.urls')),
)
```

**$ (end of line) just removed.**

Comment: DOH!  Yup, that works.  Thanks a million :)  (I have to wait 8 minutes until I can accept)

Comment: @Vadim Shender +1 exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

When something goes wrong (or even if it doesn't), thoroughly read the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).  Here's an excerpt from the aforementioned link:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^weblog/',        include('django_website.apps.blog.urls.blog')),
    (r'^documentation/', include('django_website.apps.docs.urls.docs')),
    (r'^comments/',      include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
)
```

> Note that the regular expressions in
>   this example don't have a $
>   (end-of-string match character) but do
>   include a trailing slash. Whenever
>   Django encounters include(), it chops
>   off whatever part of the URL matched
>   up to that point and sends the
>   remaining string to the included
>   URLconf for further processing.

Comment: Agreed, but I did read through the docs.  It's just easy to skim past those parts, especially when at first glance they look like the same code you're using.  I must have read past that particular passage a few times while looking for an answer.